# How can i change sort category view starting from child then parent, not alphabetically

Tags: categories, taxonomy

I have created categories by city and districts.

On the archive page, it displays well.

The problem is, the views are sorted alphabetically.

As a example :

- City (Jakarta)

  - Districts 1 (Tebet)
  - Districts 2 (Cilandak)
  - Districts 3 (Gambir)

Now displaying  :

- Cilandak Jakarta
- Gambir Jakarta
- Jakarta Tebet

I want :

- Cilandak Jakarta
- Gambir Jakarta
- Tebet Jakarta

can anyone give me some help how to change it?

Sorry if my English is bad.
thank you

I've created a snippet like this:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link','displaying_product_attributes',5);
function displaying_product_attributes () {
    global $product;
    
    
    $harga_val = $product->get_attribute('pa_harga');
    
    $kt_val = $product->get_attribute('pa_kt');
    $km_val = $product->get_attribute('pa_km');
    
    $luas_bangunan_val = $product->get_attribute('pa_luas-bangunan');
    $luas_tanah_val = $product->get_attribute('pa_luas-tanah');
    
    
        
   $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(),'product_cat' );
  if( $terms ) {
    $names = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      $names[] = $term->name;
    
    
        
    }
   
  }
    
     
    
    echo "<p style='color:#1ebf41; text-align:left; text-indent: 3px; font-size:18px;line-height: 0.5; font-weight:bold'>".$harga_val."</p>";
    
    
    echo "<p style='color:#333; text-align:left; text-indent: 3px; font-size:14px;line-height: 0.1;'><i class='fas fa-bed'></i> &nbsp;".$kt_val."&emsp;<i class='fas fa-shower'></i> &nbsp;".$km_val."&emsp;<i class='fa fa-home'></i>&nbsp; ".$luas_bangunan_val."m<sup>2</sup>&emsp;<i class='fas fa-expand-arrows-alt'></i>&nbsp; ".$luas_tanah_val."m<sup>2</sup></p>";
    
    
    print '<p style="color:#333; text-align:left; text-indent: 3px; font-size:14px;line-height: 1;"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> &nbsp; '.join( ', ', $names ).'</p>'.PHP_EOL;;
}
```

let me give you a little hint of what i want.

on settings archive page/store page, I only show title, image and add to cart button.
(on add to cart button I have edited)

I inserted some attributes and categories located before add to cart button.

at first glance looks good, but on information category that became is inverted. (sorted alphabetically) and it becomes non-uniform.

I hope you or others are still willing to help me,

the code snippet above displays the results as below

[image: please see below]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort hierarchically, try adding a sorting function to your functions.php (or plugin).

```php
// This will sort and place everything in the $into array
function sort_terms_hierarchically(Array &$cats, Array &$into, $parentId = 0) {
    foreach ($cats as $i => $cat) {
        if ($cat->parent == $parentId) {
            $cat->posts = array();
            $into[$cat->term_id] = $cat;
            unset($cats[$i]);
        }
    }

    foreach ($into as $topCat) {
        $topCat->children = array();
        sort_terms_hierarchically($cats, $topCat->children, $topCat->term_id);
    }
}
```

Now on the display side, you could grab all of your categories and display them with the parent name second.

```php
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
if ( $terms ) {
    $listItems = '';
    $sortedTerms = array(); // empty array to hold the sorted terms
    sort_terms_hierarchically( $terms, $sortedTerms ); // sort everything
    foreach( $sortedTerms as $parent) {
        if ( empty( $parent->children ) ) continue;

        foreach( $parent->children as $child ) {
            $listItems .= '<li>' . $child->name . ', ' . $parent->name . '</li>';
        }
    }
}

// Display the list
if ( !empty( $listItems ) ) {
    echo '<ul>' . $listItems . '</ul>';
}
```

Hope this better answers your question!

Comment: hi sean michael,

Sorry that I have to revise a bit about my problem.
Hope this clarifies what I want.

Comment: Hi @carlozsan, I reworked the answer for you.

Comment: hi @sean, i'm so really happy.

what you provided it worked perfectly as i wanted.

I really appreciate what you have done for me.

thank you